# How to set expiration date in constructor?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a TravelCard class that should also check if the card is still viable (not expired). But I'm having this error

> unreported exception ParseExeption; must be caught or declared to be thrown

in this line

```
this.expirationDate = sdf.parse(expiry);
```

How can I set the expiration date in constructor?

I have never used dates before as someone might notice. And also I'm fairly new in Java.

```
package something;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TravelCard {
    private double balance;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private Date expirationDate;
    private Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    public TravelCard(double balance, String expiry){
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        this.balance = balance;
        this.expirationDate = sdf.parse(expiry);
    }

    public void pay(double price){
        if (today.before(expirationDate)){
            if(this.balance >= price){
                this.balance -= price;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Card expired");
        }
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: `ParseException` is a checked exception. Please read the [exceptions tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) and decide whether you want to catch or throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, `parse()` method throws a checked exception,  either `catch` the exception or `throw`.

Way to catch the exception:

```
public void TravelCard(double balance, String expiry){
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        this.balance = balance;
         try {
             this.expirationDate = sdf.parse(expiry);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Way to throw exception:

```
 public void TravelCard(double balance, String expiry) throws ParseException{
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have a constructor that accepts a Date parameter (expirationDate) instead of the String parameter (expiry). And do the parsing of String before calling the TravelCard constructor. If you can't parse the expiry String, you can't create a TravelCard object with a valid expiration date.

```
public class TravelCard {
    private double balance;
    private final Date expirationDate;
    private final Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    public TravelCard(final double balance, final Date expirationDate) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }

    // parsing the expiry String and then calling the constructor
    public static TravelCard createTravelCard(final double balance, final String expiry) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        Date expirationDate = sdf.parse(expiry)
        return new TravelCard(balance, expiry);
    }

    // examples
    TravelCard.createTravelCard(20.0, "26/11/2016"); // TravelCard created
    TravelCard.createTravelCard(20.0, "36/11/2016"); // throws ParseException
```

Answer (score 0):

**The compiler is trying to tell you that `sdf.parse(expiry)` could fail.**  Since this method (`parse`) explicitly [`throws`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-throws/) an exception of type `ParseException` you must either place it in a [`try{..}catch(..){..}`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/) block or add the [`throws`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-throws/) declaration to the constructor.

Comment: Okay, thanks I got it working. Which way do you think is smarter: try catch or adding the throws declaration?

Comment: Generally it would depend... Use throws if you want to transfer the error and take corrective action upstream.  Use a try/catch if you can actually correct the error.  In this case, I would throw it, and use a try catch block whenever you instantiate this type.